# Load image with same name in different folders

Tags: ios, xcode, image, resources

In my Xcode project for ios, I have two images of the same name `header.png` in the following folders `folder1` and `folder2`.

When I used the following code

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
```

I get the image from folder2.

If I use

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"folder1/header.png"];
```

I get nothing.

Any idea how to access the image in folder1 and folder2?

Comment: Is the "folder" in Xcode yellow or blue? There is an important distinction in Xcode between "groups" and real "directories"

Comment: Actually you can keep your images in different res1.bundle, res2.bundle etc. Then you can load image with the same name from different bundles.
Also possible answer: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references/

Comment: yes, as Mike Weller said if physical directories reference is used in xcode you can use **UIImage** method **imageWithContentsOfFile** give image directory path with image name in argument.it only work if you create  "real directories" (Folder in blue) in xcode.

Comment: @MikeWeller
@user1548843
Ok thanks. The folder was yellow. I needed to create the folder using `references` instead of `groups`.